# how to convert the following code as a lambda expression

Tags: java

there are a number of methods:

```java
   public Map<String,String> do(Tr req){
       Map<String,String> res=new HashMap<>();
       List<Spp> list=req.getSome();
       if(null!=list) {
           for (Spp sp : list) {
               if ("op1".equals(sp.getKey())) {
                   res.put("op1", sp.getValue());
               }
               if ("op2".equals(sp.getKey())) {
                   res.put("op2", sp.getValue());
               }
               if ("op3".equals(sp.getKey())) {
                   res.put("op3", sp.getValue());
               }
           }
       }
       return res;
    }
```

```java
if ("op1".equals(sp.getKey())) {
      res.put("op1", sp.getValue());
}
```

repetitive parts want to convert lambda. I don't know what function to use.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase Are there multiple judgments in a loop?

Comment: @cheng.pro Why you need stream here. for loop looks clean.

Comment: @Daemon  Because many classes have such codes and want to remove duplication.

Comment: @Daemon The difference is that the compared strings are different.

Comment: @cheng.pro I got that, but I feel if you convert to stream then also we can't get rid of those if loops. that's the reason I said for loop looks clean

Comment: @Daemon My idea is to write a method, in the method to make equals and ```map.put()```, compare the string seat parameters passed in.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
static final Set<String> KEY_SELECTION = Set.of("op1", "op2", "op3");

public Map<String, String> doSomething(Tr req) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(req.getSome())
        .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
        .stream()
        .filter(sp -> KEY_SELECTION.contains(sp.getKey()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Spp::getKey, Spp::getValue));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest an alternative way, as you had asked for a functional interface (roughly based on @saka1029 answer, his answer is much better than mine).

Define a BiConsumer<T, U> biConsumer function

```
  private static <T, U> void resolve(T t, U u, BiConsumer<T, U> biConsumer) {
    biConsumer.accept(t, u);
  }
```

And make changes in your method as (BTW, do is a reserved keyword in java so it's not accepted as method name)

```
  public static Map<String, String> do1(Tr req) {
    Map<String, String> res = new HashMap<>();
    List<Spp> list = req.getSome();
    Set<String> operation = Set.of("op1", "op2", "op3");
    if (null != list) {
      for (Spp sp : list) {
        resolve(res,sp,
            (res1, sp1) -> {
              if (operation.contains(sp.getKey())) {
                res.put(sp.getKey(), sp.getValue());
              }
            });
      }
    }
    return res;
  }
```